# error installing and unfound package?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I'm using raspberry pi3 B and am new to the linux system (raspbian).
I was trying to build VS Code into raspberry pi3 according to: 
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi3.aspx
I've done everything accordingly...
But when I run the command in the command terminal pi@raspberrypi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/npm.sh install --arch=armhf
yarn install v1.3.2
$ node build/npm/preinstall.js
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info vscode-fsevents@0.3.8: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "vscode-fsevents@0.3.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-foreground-love@0.1.0: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-foreground-love@0.1.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-mutex@0.2.0: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-mutex@0.2.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-process-tree@0.1.6: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-process-tree@0.1.6" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/13] ⠄ gc-signals:  #ifndef INCLUDE_V8_H_
[6/13] ⠄ native-watchdog: http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v1
[3/13] ⠄ keytar: gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.7.9/
[4/13] ⠄ native-is-elevated: CXX(target) Release/obj.target/is-elevated
error /home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.9.4 | linux | arm
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.7.9/iojs-v1.7.9.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.7.9/iojs-v1.7.9.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.7.9/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.7.9/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.9/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/pi/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.9',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/pi/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.9/<(target_arch)/iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
Package xkbfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xkbfile.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xkbfile' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config x11 xkbfile --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.59-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node" "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_module
 s/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
```

I have solved the errors as shown below:
In particular:

```
error /home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap: Command failed.
```

and:

```
No package 'xkbfile' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config x11 xkbfile --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.59-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node" "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_module
 s/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/vscode/node_modules/native-keymap
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
```

Seem to work after I download libsecret and xkbfile file; but now it show these warnings in EVERY package that it tried to download upon rerunning:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/npm.sh install --arch=armhf 

warning package.json: No license field
warning code-oss-dev-smoke-test@0.1.0: No license field
```

Can this warning be ignored? And what should I do to rectify the warning?

Furthermore, I have

```
yarn install v1.3.2
warning ../../package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 45.82s.
Done in 885.46s.
```

Is it necessary to include fsevents@1.1.3?

Comment: This may be easier https://code.headmelted.com/

Comment: @SteveRobillard Ohh, ok, sure! Since I'm halfway through this method, I'll try to get it to work, but will surely explore other methods too! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings below:

```
warning package.json: No license field
warning code-oss-dev-smoke-test@0.1.0: No license field
```

are of no concern whatsoever. It just means that the author of the package didn't include a [code license](https://choosealicense.com/), so npm warns about this. It doesn't affect the running of the code in any way. You don't need to fix it, and it can safely be ignored.

You don't need [fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) either, as it's an **optional** dependency for macOS only. It doesn't do anything on Linux, so the fact that it didn't install isn't a problem.

Generally, with npm and Yarn, you should only worry if you see 'error' in the output. Both package managers are excessively verbose and spit out a lot of information that doesn't really matter too much if you're just installing a program like VS Code.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much for your help again! @Aurora0001 ; I hope the VScode works now; it's still unpacking the electron-v1.7.9-linux-arm.zip folder for quite a while now; and return with an unhandled 'error' event with Error: read ECONNRESET I think I would have to post them in another post since I dont think I can pose them here? :/ I had tried researching on how to solve the issue too, but most of the answers online direct me to connection that were manually written for an application; unlike what's happening here

Comment: Yeah, post that as a new question, @GoodCodes, with the full error, and leave a comment here when it's ready and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Sure, thanks so much! @Aurora0001 Have just posted! Sorry for the delay as I got to reboot my raspi as it froze for quite a long while suddenly when the command is running : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77742/error-read-econnreset-vs-code-on-raspi3