# Multiple instances of AudioManager detected vs code on raspi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I'm using raspberry pi3 B and am new to the linux system (raspbian). I was trying to build VS Code into raspberry pi3 according to: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi3.aspx I've done everything accordingly...

[Original Issue: ERROR: read ECONNRESET]

But when I run the command in the command terminal pi@raspberrypi at the last stage:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/code.sh
[14:37:12] Using gulpfile ~/vscode/gulpfile.js
[14:37:12] Starting 'clean-electron'...
[14:37:12] Finished 'clean-electron' after 35 ms
[14:37:12] Starting 'electron'...
↓ ffmpeg-v1.7.9-linux-arm.zip [====================] 100%
↓ electron-v1.7.9-linux-arm.zip [=================---] 87%events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:615:25)
./scripts/code.sh: line 38: /home/pi/vscode/.build/electron/code-oss: No such file or directory
```

The first time I did this it shows the same error as above and went on to starting and finishing the compilation smoothly until it reaches:

```
Finished 'compiling-extensions' after 193 us
```

and then the terminal just stop here for more than 30min; and my raspi froze; so I did a hard restart -off the power and turn on power- .

2nd try running the same command: it just stop at the no such file or directory command as shown in the first section of code above (did not proceed on to start and finish)

10+++th Try Running:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/code.sh
[15:24:56] Using gulpfile ~/vscode/gulpfile.js
[15:24:56] Starting 'clean-electron'...
[15:24:56] Finished 'clean-electron' after 22 ms
[15:24:56] Starting 'electron'...
↓ electron-v1.7.9-linux-arm.zip [====================] 100%
[15:31:33] Finished 'electron' after 6.6 min
[7903:0114/153138.657146:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[7903:0114/153138.657678:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
{ errorCode: 'load',
  moduleId: 'vs/code/electron-main/main',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous1===' ],
  detail: 
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js'
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/pi/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js' } }
```

and then it stop here for good??.... and nothing is happening.
Upon checking, there is indeed nothing in the file: `/home/pi/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js`
However, I could not find this file in github repository too as I believe that it is downloaded from somewhere among the packages... The thing is where do I get this file from...

Further repeats of the command would just return this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd vscode
pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/code.sh
[11124:0114/154915.833848:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[11124:0114/154915.834196:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
{ errorCode: 'load',
  moduleId: 'vs/code/electron-main/main',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous1===' ],
  detail: 
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js'
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/pi/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js' } }
enter code here
```

Searched online; there's people with the same error but no solution was provided

The full scripts for ./scripts/code.sh are as follow in case you need it:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
 realpath() { [[ $1 = /* ]] && echo "$1" || echo "$PWD/${1#./}"; }
 ROOT=$(dirname "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")")
else
 ROOT=$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")")
fi

function code() {
 cd "$ROOT"

 if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  NAME=`node -p "require('./product.json').nameLong"`
  CODE="./.build/electron/$NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron"
 else
  NAME=`node -p "require('./product.json').applicationName"`
  CODE=".build/electron/$NAME"
 fi

 # Node modules
 test -d node_modules || yarn

 # Get electron
 node build/lib/electron.js || ./node_modules/.bin/gulp electron

 # Build
 test -d out || ./node_modules/.bin/gulp compile

 # Configuration
 export NODE_ENV=development
 export VSCODE_DEV=1
 export VSCODE_CLI=1
 export ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1
 export ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING=1

 # Launch Code
 exec "$CODE" . "$@"
}

# Use the following to get v8 tracing:
# code --js-flags="--trace-hydrogen --trace-phase=Z --trace-deopt --code-comments --hydrogen-track-positions --redirect-code-traces" "$@"

code "$@"
```

Comment: ECONNRESET means that the connection got reset by the server. As to why that's happening... I don't know. Might be worth giving it a couple more tries to see if the download works this time round; it could just be a temporary thing. I don't think the `npm install` will do much good; if I remember correctly VS Code has to install a separate version of Electron anyway.

Comment: Ohhh, so it had nothing to do with 
./scripts/code.sh: line 38: /home/pi/vscode/.build/electron/code-oss: No such file or directory ? Do I have to rectify that? As I understand that I only have the folder named  /home/pi/vscode/build/electron/code-oss and .build does not seem to be a terminal command according to: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/commands.md

I have pasted the full scripts for ./scripts/code.sh above in my post.
Just to mention that my system is running slower and slower each time I repeat the command with lesser% of events completed.

Comment: That error is probably because the download was incomplete, so some of the directories that *should* be there didn't get downloaded correctly. That then causes the script to fail. If you can get Electron to download correctly, that'll fix the issue.

Comment: I realised that when I keep retrying pi@raspberrypi:~/vscode $ ./scripts/code.sh ,this zip folder is no longer repeated too:  ↓ ffmpeg-v1.7.9-linux-arm.zip [====================] 100% . Is this normal? 

Do you kindly have any suggestions on how to get Electron to download correctly? Is the only way out for me to keep re-entering the ./scripts/code.sh command? I have managed to get Electron to download to 100% but another error occur as edited in the post above. Thank you!

Comment: That's an odd error; perhaps it might be easier if you just cut your losses and try the [community build, as suggested by Steve Robillard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77724/error-installing-and-unfound-package#comment122651_77724) on your other question. I couldn't find any hint as to why this error would happen; the error seems to suggest that the main file doesn't exist at all, which is a bad sign.

Comment: oh ok sure; does that mean I have to uninstall the files that I've downloaded (in particular, vscode) or am I able to leave them as it is and just follow the community build and install straight? Would there be a possibility of overwritten and unstable files as a result

Comment: You should be okay to leave them there; I don't think it'll cause any harm. If it does, you can always delete them later on.